# git commit with date before 1973 fails

Tags: git, epoch

I have the following strange problem

```
λ git version
git version 2.18.0.windows.1

λ git config --global log.date iso8601

λ git commit --date=1970-01-01 -m "change"
fatal: invalid date format: @40769

λ git commit --date=1973-01-30 -m "change"
fatal: invalid date format: @97240598

λ git commit --date=1973-03-30 -m "change"
nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

I was expecting to be able to run the command for anything after 1970-01-01.

---

Update after @Lasse question

```
λ git commit --date='1973-03-02' -m test1
fatal: invalid date format: @99945655

λ git commit --date='1973-03-03' -m test1
no changes added to commit

λ git commit --date='1973-03-02T00:00:00' -m test1
no changes added to commit

λ git commit --date='1973-03-03T00:00:00' -m test1
no changes added to commit
```

So it happens going from `1973-03-02` to `1973-03-03`.

Tested with same results in: `2.11.0.windows.1` and `2.18.0.windows.1`

Comment: Does `--date='1970-01-01T00:00:00'` work?

Comment: @gzh 30th of January 1973 is prior to 1970?

Comment: @Lasse - I added more details after your suggestion. By the way I'm on windows: `git version 2.11.0.windows.1`

Comment: Any reason why you're not on the latest version? Not that I think this will matter but still...

Comment: Judging by your edit, it doesn't seem to change from 1973-03-02 to 1973-03-03 as long as you provide the time, let me ask again: Does `--date='1970-01-01T00:00:00'` work? (this is a yes/no question by the way)

Comment: Yes.  It works with  `--date='1970-01-01T00:00:00`

Comment: This looks/smells like a bug in the date parser (which is very complex, as it tries to accept all kinds of user specified dates, and deal with time zone issues).

Comment: Yup. Somehow those dates don't trigger a timezone getting added to the resulting stamp.